# Define a typescript module

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm new to webpack, I created a project whit it, but when I import it in Angular app, it says: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "1.0.16",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/my-lib/index.ts",
  "types": "./dist/my-lib/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.cjs"
  },
 
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.2"
  }
```

}

`webpack.common.cjs`

```
 module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.ts'),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'my-lib.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/my-lib'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
};
```

In angular app I have imported the comp in ts file:

import {Comp} from 'my-lib'